# How to carry objects through different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have this issue where I have an array of objects called covidrecordArray[], and I need to select certain objects from this array. Here is my object:

`Public Class CovidRecord`

```
public Country(String pIso3, String pContinent, String pCountryName, String Nuts, Double pLatitude, Double pLongitude)
```

I also have my constructors and my setters and getters already done.
I have 1777 objects, with some of these being under SA. This is my selector

`public class Main`

```
public static void Main(String[] args)

{

String target = "SA";
String[] SASortedArray = new String[107]    // this 107 is the manually found number of objects with SA
for(int j = 0; j < SASortedArray.length; j++){
     for(int i = 0; i < 1777; i ++) {    // 1777 is length of my array of objects
          if (covidrecordArray[i].Country.continent == target) {
                 SASortedArray[j] = String.valueOf(covidrecordArray[i]);
                 return;
          }
      }
}
```

When I try to access SASortedArray at a specific object point, it goes red and does not work

```
int SATotalOne = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 1777; i++) {
    SATotalOne = += SASortedArray.cumulativePositive // the .cumulativePositive goes red
}
System.out.println("SATotalOne)
```

The .cumulativePositive goes red and I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you wrote

```
int SATotalOne = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 1777; i++) {
SATotalOne = += SASortedArray.cumulativePositive
}
System.out.println("SATotalOne)
```

when I think it should be

```
    int SATotalOne = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 1777; i++) {
SATotalOne += SASortedArray[i].cumulativePositive;  
}
System.out.println("SATotalOne);
```

Comment: this didnt work

Comment: Actually you are using a string array 
change this :
   String[] SASortedArray = new String[107] 
to this : 
String[] SASortedArray = new DATA_TYPE[107] 

DATA_TYPE is the class which contains cumulativePositive attribute